# unalbe to create destination directory for ant target in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am learning `ant build-tool` and got stuck in first build, I tried my best but was not able to find the solution on how to create destination folder dynamically as I have the following `build.xml`

```
<project name="Ant Demo" default="run">
    <target name="run" description="run method" depends="compile">
        <java classname="com.demo.HelloWorld">
            <classpath path="target" />
        </java>
        <echo>Run is complete</echo>
    </target>
    <target name="compile" description="target compile">
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="." destdir="target" />

    </target>
</project>
```

actually I am following a **[`turorial`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERbyZlyM_d4)** and according to which the destination directory is supposed to create sub-folders automatically but is not working,

**edit** the output I'm getting is

```
compile:
run:
     [java] running tasks
     [echo] Run is complete
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 359 milliseconds
```

but I cannot see any sub-folder as sub-directory of target folder

How to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like your ant tasks are running as intented because there are no error messages in your posted ant logs.
in `target` directory your class files are generated but you don't see them because eclipse does not automatically refresh that folder.

you can see them by `right click` on target folder > `refresh`.

or to automatize

right click on build.xml (your ant xml) > Run as > Ant Build... > Refresh tab > Refresh resources upon completion > The project containing the selected resource > Apply

or,

in your ant build file, add

```
<eclipse.refreshLocal resource="target" />
```

after the line

```
<javac includeantruntime ...
```

and right click on build.xml (your ant xml) > Run as > Ant Build... > JRE tab > Run in the same jre as workspace > Apply

Comment: thanks for reply, now I got the directory structure but I need to get class files inside that structure too(which was the ultimate goal of question), If you won't mind can you tell me how to do that(just a hint)